# Visual Studio solution parser

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm looking for a tool that reads a .sln file and parses out all the sub projects and then parses all the sub project files into a list so that I can write a build list for a release?

I just want the directory structure of the entier solution minus any excess that may exist in the solution's directory structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Library for parsing Visual Studio Solution files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707107/library-for-parsing-visual-studio-solution-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted an answer to this question which you might find helpful. I'm using the SolutionParser, an internal class of the Microsoft.Build framework, which handles solution files.

[Library for parsing Visual Studio Solution files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707107/library-for-parsing-visual-studio-solution-files)

Answer (score 2):

I am looking for that tool myself, but did not find any.

But the contents of the SLN file is pretty easy to parse, so I am trying to write such a tool for my companies build process. I will post any progress.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing myself. I did notice a pain in the butt while looking at the sub project files. As there are many ItemGroup nodes in the project file you would have to perform a search for <CompileFile></CompileFile> tags to get the files. I think with some work it can be done. If I find anything I'll post it here as well.