# Update project property with a powershell script

Tags: powershell, msbuild, nuget, csproj

I want to create a nuget package which will run a Powershell script on restore in a C# project. The script will change the values of the project properties on the project e.g.:

Set value of

```
<AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
```

to

```
<AssemblyVersion>$(ReleaseApplicationVersion)</AssemblyVersion>
```

and some other properties.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE-------------------------------------------

This is what I have

```
param([string]$projectName = $(throw 'csproj file is required'))

$proj = Resolve-Path $projectName

$propAssemblyName = $proj.Properties.Item("AssemblyName")
$propAssemblyName.Value = '$(ReleasedAssemblyName)'
```

But I obviously dont know how to make this work as I get bunch of issues. Thanks

Comment: Please show how far you have gotten and ask a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying Visual Studio solution and project files with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718065/modifying-visual-studio-solution-and-project-files-with-powershell)

Answer (score 2):

```
function Set-Version {
    Write-Header "Updating version in .csproj files"
 
    try {
        Push-Location ".\csprojLocation"
        $versionProjFile = Resolve-Path "*.csproj"
        $xml = [xml](Get-Content $versionProjFile)
        $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.AssemblyVersion = ${version}
        $xml.Save($versionPropsFile)
    }
    finally {
        Pop-Location
    }
}
 
Set-Version
```