# Parse a .Net 4 Solution File

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am facing a problem in which there are numerous projects in .net , all saved to a particular location, most of which are just the default ones which are generated by the wizards.

There are projects which are just having the default structure.

I am thinking about reading the XML from the project files to know which files/references are present in the solution.

But, how to know if the noob has made a default project.

Do I need to use a .Net parser for the code file?

For Example, In a c# default project there are some standard assemblies referenced, and a default .cs file created with a standard function.

Comment: How do you determine the difference between a default project and one created by a wizard? As far as I know, the project files follow the same schema.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Library for parsing Visual Studio Solution files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707107/library-for-parsing-visual-studio-solution-files)

Comment: Well - the structure of a project isn't stored in a solution file anyway (which is also *text*, not XML) - I think you need to parse the XML of the project file - for which you could simply use Linq to XML

Comment: @Oded : Yup, the schema is same. But how can we tell that the project is doing some actual work or just displaying the default Window Form.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan : thnx for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution files are text based rather than XML.  There is information on their format here [Solution (.sln) File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Most project files (e.g. .csproj files) are in the MSBuild file format which is XML based.  A standard XML parser can be used to read these files and the file format is documented here [MSBuild Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The solution file isn't xml, but there are parsers look at this topic:

[Parsing Visual Studio Solution files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707107/library-for-parsing-visual-studio-solution-files)