# How to get all projects name in a solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

How to get all projects name in a solution via C#?
The solution has console projects in which there are many windows services.

My goal is to find all projects name then to get all windows services name in the projects.

The implement will be done in a new project in the same solution.
Thanks for hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb165951%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) that will resolve your query.

> The .sln file contains text-based information the environment uses to
>   find and load the name-value parameters for the persisted data and the
>   project VSPackages it references. When a user opens a solution, the
>   environment cycles through the preSolution, Project, and postSolution
>   information in the .sln file to load the solution, projects within the
>   solution, and any persisted information attached to the solution.

Also check [EnvDTE : Getting all projects](http://www.wwwlicious.com/2011/03/29/envdte-getting-all-projects-html) .

Also check this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707107/library-for-parsing-visual-studio-solution-files)(Full credit to **John Leidegren** for providing such a nice answer)

```
public class Solution
{
    //internal class SolutionParser
    //Name: Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionParser
    //Assembly: Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0

    static readonly Type s_SolutionParser;
    static readonly PropertyInfo s_SolutionParser_solutionReader;
    static readonly MethodInfo s_SolutionParser_parseSolution;
    static readonly PropertyInfo s_SolutionParser_projects;

    static Solution()
    {
        s_SolutionParser = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionParser, Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", false, false);
        if (s_SolutionParser != null)
        {
            s_SolutionParser_solutionReader = s_SolutionParser.GetProperty("SolutionReader", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            s_SolutionParser_projects = s_SolutionParser.GetProperty("Projects", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            s_SolutionParser_parseSolution = s_SolutionParser.GetMethod("ParseSolution", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        }
    }

    public List<SolutionProject> Projects { get; private set; }

    public Solution(string solutionFileName)
    {
        if (s_SolutionParser == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can not find type 'Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionParser' are you missing a assembly reference to 'Microsoft.Build.dll'?");
        }
        var solutionParser = s_SolutionParser.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).First().Invoke(null);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(solutionFileName))
        {
            s_SolutionParser_solutionReader.SetValue(solutionParser, streamReader, null);
            s_SolutionParser_parseSolution.Invoke(solutionParser, null);
        }
        var projects = new List<SolutionProject>();
        var array = (Array)s_SolutionParser_projects.GetValue(solutionParser, null);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            projects.Add(new SolutionProject(array.GetValue(i)));
        }
        this.Projects = projects;
    }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("{ProjectName}, {RelativePath}, {ProjectGuid}")]
public class SolutionProject
{
    static readonly Type s_ProjectInSolution;
    static readonly PropertyInfo s_ProjectInSolution_ProjectName;
    static readonly PropertyInfo s_ProjectInSolution_RelativePath;
    static readonly PropertyInfo s_ProjectInSolution_ProjectGuid;

    static SolutionProject()
    {
        s_ProjectInSolution = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectInSolution, Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", false, false);
        if (s_ProjectInSolution != null)
        {
            s_ProjectInSolution_ProjectName = s_ProjectInSolution.GetProperty("ProjectName", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            s_ProjectInSolution_RelativePath = s_ProjectInSolution.GetProperty("RelativePath", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            s_ProjectInSolution_ProjectGuid = s_ProjectInSolution.GetProperty("ProjectGuid", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        }
    }

    public string ProjectName { get; private set; }
    public string RelativePath { get; private set; }
    public string ProjectGuid { get; private set; }

    public SolutionProject(object solutionProject)
    {
        this.ProjectName = s_ProjectInSolution_ProjectName.GetValue(solutionProject, null) as string;
        this.RelativePath = s_ProjectInSolution_RelativePath.GetValue(solutionProject, null) as string;
        this.ProjectGuid = s_ProjectInSolution_ProjectGuid.GetValue(solutionProject, null) as string;
    }
}
```

Comment: To use the thread's solution, I have to use Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop. I can't find it in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: It is there in Visual Studio 2012. Check this:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164686.aspx

Comment: Why repost [another StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4634505/1810243) in your own answer... even if you do give credit.

Comment: I was trying to get the AssemblyName(s) for all my csproj, using the solution file.  This rocked.  Here is the code to get the full path of each "SolutionProject".         System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(solutionFileName), currentSolutionProject.RelativePath);

Answer (score 5):

This will be easier using the new [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) API

```
var workspace=MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;
var projects = solution.Projects;
foreach(var project in projects)
{
  //TODO              
}
```