# Visual Studio: What is the format of "*.sln" file? It's not xml

Tags: xml, file, solution

I used text editor to open an .sln file, it looks like a tree structure, but it's not xml format.

Do you know what format it is, and can we process it using C#, like processing xml conveniently?

Comment: I've never understood why MS decided to not use XML format for .sln files.  They did use XML for proj files! :p

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/solution-dot-sln-file?view=vs-2022

Comment: re "can we process it using C#" See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707107/parsing-visual-studio-solution-files

Answer (score 12):

Here is the description of the format: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951(v=vs.140).aspx

You're right, it is not XML, but another text-based format:

> The .sln file contains text-based information the environment uses to
>   find and load the name-value parameters for the persisted data and the
>   project VSPackages it references.

And for parsing the file you can look at this question: [Parsing Visual Studio Solution files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707107/library-for-parsing-visual-studio-solution-files)

Answer (score 3):

Add [Microsoft.Build](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build/) from NuGet and then:

```cs
using Microsoft.Build.Construction;
var sln = SolutionFile.Parse(filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

https://github.com/tapika/syncProj

`Solution.LoadSolution` will decrypt solution information for you in code.