# Get list of projects from Visual Studio .sln file using Microsoft.Build namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, microsoft.build

I figured out how to load a .csproj file using the Microsoft.Build namespace and extract a couple of properties:

```
var projectCollection = new ProjectCollection();
projectCollection.LoadProject(@"C:\path\to\my.csproj");
string assemblyName = projectCollection.LoadedProjects.First().GetPropertyValue("AssemblyName");
string outputPath = projectCollection.LoadedProjects.First().GetPropertyValue("OutputPath");
```

Now how can I use Microsoft.Build to load a .sln file and get the list of .csproj files?

Comment: It would be better to [edit] your question and add the additional information there. It's not only easier for others to see, but it can be properly formatted for readability.

Comment: Dupe to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707107/parsing-visual-studio-solution-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For parsing solution file you can use [`SolutionFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.construction.solutionfile) class:

```
var solutionFile = SolutionFile.Parse(@"SOLUTION_PATH.sln");
var projectNames = solutionFile.ProjectsInOrder.Select(p => p.ProjectName).ToList();
```